# What the purpose of the frameTimeNanos in the Choreographer.FrameCallback.doFrame

Tags: android, android-studio, animation, vsync

In Choreographer.FrameCallback.doFrame event, their a value called `frameTimeNanos`. what exactly mean this value and more important how to use it, I mean in with scenario we need to take care of this value?